# Google Analytics Reporting API V3/V4 compatibility with Google Analytics 4 (GA4)

Tags: google-analytics

Today we use Google Analytics Reporting API V3 (core reporting API v3 using java SDK google-api-services-analytics-v3-revxxxx.jar) in our system to connect and get data from Google Analytics. For this, we need properties that are based on Universal Analytics (UA-xxxx). We use the service account approach for connecting to Google Analytics and fetching data.

**From looking at the information available at https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting it seems that we cannot use the v3 API with the new GA4 properties and we would have to use Data API V1. Is this correct?** Any information around this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the data model of GA4 is completely different from that of Universal Analytics for which dedicated APIs are required.
To date, GA4 is still young and constantly evolving so many new improvements and features will come out in the near short future also from a programmatic point of view.

Anyway you can still create a Universal Analytics Property by 'show more option' button when you create a new one.